# How to get ActiveMQ - FIFO requirement for single sender and receiver?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am using single Sender and Receiver for Sending Object Message.Is this possible to achieve FIFO with out any extra configuration or I have to do something.

I have to means, Please tell me what I have to do ?

I am using PTP Messaging.

Whenever I want to send Message , I am creating a connection and sending message and close the connection.but receiver will be listening forever to receive messages.Receiver end must be FIFO.

I read about single sender and Multiple receiver and other combination .I didn't get anything  about single sender to single receiver.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A queue is by definition FIFO. So in general the answer to your question is yes.

(Then, in the real world, it can get arbitrarily complicated with filtering, messages going to back out queues for failed processing or the backing DB balking or whatever...)

Your "single sender multiple receiver" would likely be the Topic/[publish-subscriber pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) - have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576415/jms-topic-vs-queues).

Cheers,