# How to consume two subscriber (subscribed to same query) to one?

Tags: java, jms, publish-subscribe, jms-topic

I have two subscribers, subscribed to same query, but I want only one to consume it. How can I achieve it using map or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by _query_?  Messages published to a topic will be received by all subscribers.  Messages published to a queue will be received by only one of the subscribers.  Possibly terminology conflict - see pub/sub vs message queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one consumer to get the message, use **queue receivers** instead of **topic subscribers**. The purposes of queues is exactly that: one-to-one delivery. See also this discussion: [JMS Topic vs Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576415/jms-topic-vs-queues)